# jquery colorbox open single image

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have an image in a repeater, I only want to open the image which has been clicked on,  I don't want the other images to be available to do paging.

This is my line in the repeater:

```html
<a title="jhddj" rel="relImageStatusUpdate" href="<%= format_status_image_url(row["UserID"],row["USERSTATUS_ID"]) %>" 
id="ahrefStatusImage"> 
<img alt="" 
src="<%= format_status_thumbnailimage_url(row["UserID"],row["USERSTATUS_ID"]) %>"/></a>
```

And the jquery is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a[rel='relImageStatusUpdate']").colorbox();

});
```

Comment: Explain better what you need, and why you are using colorbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `rel` to `relImageStatusUpdate`, change it to `nofollow`. This is from the [ColorBox Docs](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

> `rel: false` This can be used as an
>   anchor rel alternative for ColorBox.
>   This allows the user to group any
>   combination of elements together for a
>   gallery, or to override an existing
>   rel so elements are not grouped
>   together. Example: $('#example
>   a').colorbox({rel:'group1'})
>
> **Note: The
>   value can also be set to 'nofollow' to
>   disable grouping.**

and of course initialize Colorbox as follows:

```
$("a[rel='nofollow']").colorbox();
```